# Adding a text and progress icon to navigation bar

Tags: ios

I would like to add a status to the navigation bar. for example, in Whatsapp, when user changes alert settings, It display "updating" text and progress icon on the navigation bar, as shown in below image.
How do i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple add a separate view in your XIB, something like image below

[image]

And create IBOutlet of all the components, and then you can do something like below

```
self.navigationItem.titleView=self.progressView; //progressView IBOutlet of the container view progressView
```

in `viewDidLoad`

then you can create a function like

```
-(void)showProgress{
   self.lblUpdate.text=@"Updating...";
   [self.indicator startAnimating];
}

-(void)hideProgress{
   self.lblUpdate.text=@"Updated";
   [self.indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Make sure you make the view background color `clearColor`, and make the indicator to `hideWhenStopped`.

Hope it helps.